# My Windows service is reading 100's of files with thousands of records in each file and inserting in to Sql server using threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

My Windows service is reading 100's of files with thousands of records  in each file and inserting in to Sql server using threading. Currently how i am doing this is by using `Threads`. I am running 4 threads and each `Thread` will pick one file and process till the files end and then I insert all the read records in to database. Then this thread will pick new Un-processed file. All 4 threads will behave in the same. But this process is taking long time.

Is there any better way to achieve this.

I need to complete this operation faster then what it is now.

Comment: the question is vague and asks for opinions..that's not how this site works I believe... I would suggest add code and put a specific question as to what have you tried, what is working and what is not working.

Comment: Depends on the bottleneck - you need to profile to find out what part of your application is taking the time... it may be network/disk IO or it could be amount of time spent computing values in whatever algorithm you have running in the threads. You can use `StopWatch` at different points of the code in the absence of any profiling tools

Comment: The bottleneck is while reading the files using the threads.

Comment: Are your files opened with reading access only? Do you load the complete file in memory first?

Comment: Are you sure that is where the bottleneck is, have you run a code profiler or are you guessing? Please include the code showing how you are reading the files in.

Comment: Currently I am opening the files with read access only. Code is in office system. I am at home now. I can share the code on Monday.

Comment: I would second the need for profiling to determine the bottleneck, but would't advise the use of the `StopWatch` class when you can avoid it. Visual Studio has a perfectly good instrumenting profiler built-in.

Comment: On an oldfashionned HDD using more than 1 thread is usually slower. This better be about a RAID or a SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just importing data, you're probably better off doing a [BULK INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

Also, if you have multiple threads reading from the same disk at the same time, your program will probably be slower than if it was running single threaded. That's especially true if the per-record processing time is very short. You're better off using just two threads, like this.

```
while not end of input
{
    read a batch of records from the disk
    wait for pending asynchronous SQL insert operation to complete
    start asynchronous SQL insert operation with
}
```

So while one thread is inserting records, the main thread is reading the next batch of records from the disk.

If you have multiple threads reading from the disk, then those threads spend a lot of time waiting on the hardware. The disk can only do one thing at a time, and disk seeks aren't free. In addition, depending on your database server, it might perform slower with multiple threads doing inserts than if a single thread were doing the insert.

Really, though, if the insert is just an import of the disk file, then BULK INSERT is almost certainly going to perform faster than your C# program.

Comment: One thing I missed to explain here is "I am reading files that exits on different servers from my machine for Processing.

Comment: @Vinay: If they're on different servers then you have the network bottleneck to deal with. If your multiple threads saturate the network bandwidth, then it's quite possible that the multiple threads are making it slower. You really need to profile your code and determine for certain where the bottleneck is. It's probably easiest to do that with a single thread. Then you can think about optimizing the program with multiple threads, if your profiling indicates that it would be beneficial.